# Find out into how many values a return value will be unpacked

Tags: python

I have a function, and when it is called, I'd like to know what the return value is going to be assigned to - specifically when it is unpacked as a tuple. So:

```
a = func()         # n = 1
```

vs.

```
a, b, c = func()   # n = 3
```

I want to use the value of `n` in `func`. There must be some magic with `inspect` or `_getframe` that lets me do this. Any ideas?

---

Disclaimer (because this seems to be neccessary nowadays): I know this is funky, and bad practice, and shouldn't be used in production code. It actually looks like something I'd expect in Perl. I'm not looking for a different way to solve my supposed "actual" problem, but I'm curious how to achive what I asked for above. One cool usage of this trick would be:

```
ONE, TWO, THREE = count()
ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR = count()
```

with

```
def count():
    n = get_return_count()
    if not n:
        return
    return range(n)
```

Comment: You can check the length of returned value and do assignments based on that length.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? You can know from the function itself how many items will returned, or you can simply `len(foo())` in the caller. I have a feeling this is a case of a solution looking for a problem.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: No, I'm still in the function `func` and haven't returned anything yet, so I can't call `len`. If the caller does `a,b = func()`, I'll return 2 elements. If the caller does `a,b,c = func()`, I'll return 3. I want to know in func what the caller will do with the return value.

Comment: Why? What is the point of this?  Typically such thing are written in the documentation of the function.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I want to know how many items I **can** return (inside `func`). The main technical reason is to avoid the "Too many values to unpack" error. I don't need this, there is no problem. I'm just curious - see it as a coding challenge.

Comment: @jdm But it's impossible for a function to know where it's returned value is going to be assigned, better pass that length to the function; `a,b = func(2)` ; `a,b,c = func(3)` and return only those number of values.

Comment: @jdm - you can return ONE item, that can be unpacked into three, so what's the point?

Comment: You may want to skim through the archives of [python-ideas](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-ideas) from a few months ago. Someone suggested adding an "unpack protocol" separate from the iterator protocol, which would make something like this almost trivial. IIRC, the idea was shot down, but some "hacky  implementations in today's Python" were suggested along the way.

Answer (score 11):

Adapted from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/284742-finding-out-the-number-of-values-the-caller-is-exp/:

```
import inspect
import dis

def expecting(offset=0):
    """Return how many values the caller is expecting"""
    f = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back
    i = f.f_lasti + offset
    bytecode = f.f_code.co_code
    instruction = ord(bytecode[i])
    if instruction == dis.opmap['UNPACK_SEQUENCE']:
        return ord(bytecode[i + 1])
    elif instruction == dis.opmap['POP_TOP']:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def count():
    # offset = 3 bytecodes from the call op to the unpack op
    return range(expecting(offset=3))
```

Or as an object that can detect when it is unpacked:

```
class count(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        # offset = 0 because we are at the unpack op
        return iter(range(expecting(offset=0)))
```

Comment: +1: this is a better hack than mine because it's going to get at the right assignment.

Comment: for py3 remove the `ord()` calls

Answer (score 7):

There is little magic about how Python does this.

Simply put, if you use more than one target name on the left-hand side, the right-hand expression must return a *sequence* of matching length.

Functions that return more than one value really just return **one** tuple. That is a standard Python structure, a sequence of a certain length. You can measure that length:

```
retval = func()

print len(retval)
```

Assignment unpacking is determined at *compile time*, you cannot dynamically add more arguments on the left-hand side to suit the function you are calling.

Python 3 lets you use a splat syntax, a wildcard, for capturing the remainder of a unpacked assignment:

```
a, b, *c = func()
```

`c` will now be a list with any remaining values beyond the first 2:

```
>>> def func(*a): return a
... 
>>> a, b, *c = func(1, 2)
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, [])
>>> a, b, *c = func(1, 2, 3)
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, [3])
>>> a, b, *c = func(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```