# Matching Iterators With Discard In Python

Tags: python, iterator, pattern-matching

Is there any way to do what this implies:

```
a, b, ... = count()
```

The idea is to match the first two values from the (infinite, in this case) iterator, and discard the rest.

The best I can do is the clunky:

```
a, b = islice(count(), 0, 2)
```

which requires you to count the number of entries on the left hand side.

Is there a cool hack I am missing?

Comment: Joke: `globals().update(dict(zip(('a','b'), count())))`?

Comment: is there any way to grab a function argument's name (by inspecting frames?)?  if so, that could be implemented as a function...  oh, no perhaps it couldn't.  i guess the scope would be wrong.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481156/find-out-into-how-many-values-a-return-value-will-be-unpacked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no simple way to that unless you explicitly tell the amount of elements you want.

There has been a lot of discussion (I think in the end of last year when they were introducing [the `enum` library](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/)) in the Python-ideas mail group about this and nobody could agree to a way of solving this problem.

For **finite** iterators, on Python 3 you can use:

```
a, b, *_ = thing()
```

Where the `_` variable may be ignored.

Comment: thanks.  not surprisingly, perhaps, i am also thinking of enums...  the *_ thing is cute and i had no idea it existed (can't mark answers correct yet due to time limit)

Comment: `*_` will evaluate the whole iterator.

Comment: @andrewcooke `_` is just a throwaway name. It will evaluate the whole iterator, so only use on finite ones!

Comment: yeah i realise that - i didn't realise the * prefix could be used there.

Comment: @andrewcooke It is very handy for separating first/last elements of a list: `a, *b = [1, 2, 3]`