# Allow user to read only first variable of the return of function in python

Tags: python, tuples, return-value

I have a function like ("stupid minimal example"):

```
def f(n):
  a = n*n
  b = a+1
  return b

b0 = f(n) # used million times in the code
```

**I want to change `def f() :` in such a way that this works:**

```
def f(n)
  a = n*n
  b = a+1
  somemagicreturn b,a

b0 = f(n) # gives b0 == n*n+1
b0,a0 = f(n) #gives b0 == n*n+1 and a0==n*n
```

If possible, without having additional arguments to `f` and without having two functions `f` and `f2`.

---

In Matlab, this is possible, in the following way:

File `f.m`:

```
function [r1,r2]=f(n)
if nargout == 2,
  r1 = n*n+1
  r2 = n*n
else,
  r1 = n*n+1
end,
```

Or even simpler:

```
function [r1,r2]=f(n)
r1 = n*n+1
r2 = n*n
```

Both of the above used as:

```
b = f(0) 
[b,a] = f(0)
```

(The first returns `b=1` and the second `b=1, a=0`, as I want.)

Comment: Its supposed to be `a = n**2`

Comment: @KDawG Or probably not... It's a valid operator as well

Comment: @KDawG Sorry, I use `sage` where `^` works. I'll edit, still it's not substantial I think.

Comment: Also in the second example, i think you meant `b=a+1`.

Comment: @alKid Yep. (Damn, one makes so sure not to make any mistakes. Originally I had `k,l` instead of `a,b` and then realized that `l` is not a good choice...)

Comment: return (b, a) should do the trick. Unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I don't believe that you can do this in Python without modifying any of the code that already uses `f`. If `f` returns multiple values, then it will be returning a tuple (or a dictionary, or a class, or some other container object). Python won't silently unpack this tuple for calls which are expecting just an int to be returned.

Comment: @qwrrty And you can't access the number of guys to return either, probably...

Comment: @KDawG Your answer was right! undelete it, i'll upvote

Comment: @aIKid BTW wasnt it supposed to be *without modifying the code*

Comment: @KDawG without modifying *the function*. Your solution was right. The OP is missing some fundamental understanding here..

Comment: Hang on.. wait a second..

Comment: @aIKid sorry, vhere do you read "without modifying the function"? I want to modify the function, I don't want to 1) modify tonnes of code that uses it, and 2) having the two functions differing just by returning a second thing or not. (As I use to have often in Matlab)

Comment: Yeah, i think i misread something.

Comment: Please tell me, is the question really _so unclear_? Because so far, none of the answers do what was asked for. They either change the way how `f` is called, or use a second function name `g`, which is of course possible, but I prefer to avoid this.

Comment: @tohecz *yeah* give it a edit with more clarification.... also post a working sage example

Comment: Could this be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481156/find-out-into-how-many-values-a-return-value-will-be-unpacked

Comment: or directly from the course, you can find what you want here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/284742-finding-out-the-number-of-values-the-caller-is-exp/

Comment: @RudyBunel It might be a duplicate even, that I wasn't able to find. I gotta go now, see you later.

Comment: @tohecz I added a new reply and tested it, it works with your test case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making a different answer because it's a different approach.
All credits goes [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/284742-finding-out-the-number-of-values-the-caller-is-exp/), I just adapted it to your case.

Still, probably not a best practice by far IMHO.

```
import inspect, dis

def expecting():
    """Return how many values the caller is expecting"""
    f = inspect.currentframe()
    f = f.f_back.f_back
    c = f.f_code
    i = f.f_lasti
    bytecode = c.co_code
    instruction = ord(bytecode[i + 3])
    if instruction == dis.opmap['UNPACK_SEQUENCE']:
        howmany = ord(bytecode[i + 4])
        return howmany
    elif instruction == dis.opmap['POP_TOP']:
        return 0
    return 1


def f(n):
    howmany = expecting()
    a = n * n
    b = a + 1
    if howmany == 1:
        return b
    else:
        return b, a

a = f(1)
print a # this prints 2

a, b = f(1)
print a # this prints 2 
print b # this prints 1
```

Comment: +1 and accept, this works and from all the non-pythonian solutions here looks the clearest. The best would be if python implemented `nargout`, for example as a part of `inspect` (which seems to be capable of dirty tricks anyways).

Comment: Doesn't work correctly with "a, *b = f(1)" (expected() returns 1), though mine does. ("a, *b = f(1)" uses [starred tuple unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#specification) (starred tuple unpacking is only available in Python 3). To make it work on Python 3, one has to remove the two ord() function calls (`ord(bytecode[i + 4])` should be `bytecode[i + 4]`).

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I have no permission to add comment currently.

Can I modify function f ?

If yes, you can add a keyword option with a default value:

```
def f(n, nopt=2):
  a = n^2
  b = b+1
  if nopt == 2 :
    return b,a
  else :
    return b
```

Comment: Congrats on your first python answer! +1 for that :)

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: Nice, however, is the same as implementing `f2` that just returns two things. Please guys, maybe my question isn't perfect, but I know all these basic things I can do :)

Comment: In your solution, I need to run `b0,a0=f(0,2)` for something that I want to be `b0,a0=f(0)`. This is quite frowned upon for me (and I thought it is clear that this is not a good solution).

Comment: @tohecz Yes, my answer is wrong for your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481156 this may help.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative s̶o̶l̶u̶t̶i̶o̶n̶  ugly hack which parses the code calling it and requires absolutely **no** modification of code calling f(). It uses the inspect and ast module, so add the imports for them.

`inspect.stack()[2 if called_from_function else 1][4][0]` gets the code where `f()` is being called.

```
import inspect
import ast

def num_assigns():
    calling_code = inspect.stack()[2][4][0]
    calling_code = calling_code.lstrip() # Strip the identation
    first = ast.parse(calling_code).body[0]
    blocks = (ast.FunctionDef, ast.ClassDef, ast.For, ast.While, ast.If, ast.While, ast.TryExcept, ast.TryFinally)
    # Handle the case of the assignment being in a block
    if isinstance(first, blocks):
        first = first.body[0]
    if not isinstance(first, ast.Assign): return 0
    targets = first.targets
    if isinstance(targets[0], ast.Tuple):
      return len(targets[0].elts)
    if isinstance(targets, list):
      return len(targets)

    assert False, "This part should never be reached"

def fruits():
  print(num_assigns())
  return "apple", "orange"

if True:
  apple, orange = fruits()
```

Just call num_assigns() from f() to find out the number of values the return value is being assigned to. Note that it will not work in the Python interactive console as num_assigns() reads the code from the file. Also, num_assigns() assumes it is being called from a function, if not then set the called_from_function argument to False.

Comment: This looks like a promising approach. I gotta go, I'll be back later! Thanks for the effort!

Comment: You just won the UglyHackFTW Award, Sir !-)

Comment: It's a pity that someone down-voted this since UglyHackFTW is obviously the only way to go to achieve the goal in Python and this seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the number of the return values expected to the function:

```
def f(returns=1, n):
    a = n**2
    b = a+1
    return (a, b)[:returns]
```

With `returns` as the amount of values to be returned.

Comment: I undeleted this, in case modifying the function is what you wanted.

Comment: So all calls of `f` I've implemented so far in my code have to be modified, right?

Comment: No need if you specify a default argument n=1

Comment: Ahh.. so that's what you meant. Of course, there's no evading that provided this is the case.

Comment: Adding a keyword argument still means each call that expected two returned values will have to be modified.

Comment: @tohecz After coding python for some time, i believe that there is no direct solution for your question. Sorry, but that's all i can help.

Comment: @aIKid agree the OP must understand this is **python** not *matlab*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to return two values and make it only receive the first value but you could add:

```
global a0
the code for computing a
a0 = a
```

and then after the function is called a0 would be set to a.

Comment: @tohecz I saw that, but how does my code require modification of existing code? It does assume that a0 is used for the second value.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get what you've done here. No, sorry, that's not really a thing one wants to do. It's not stable under recursion, etc. Certainly not a good coding practice. Still I apologize, my comment was irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps do something like this:

```
def g(n):
  a = n*n
  b = a+1
  return b,a

def f(n):
    b,_ = g(n)
    return b
```

That way you can use `g` when you want all the answers and keep on using `f` for your existing code.
It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, I can do this, quite certainly. The question is whether I can do it in such a way that both `b0=f(n)` and `b0,a0=f(n)` work as expected. Not `b0=f(n)` and `b0,a0=g(n)`. That's something I do now, and I hate it.